# elixir multiple arguments with the pipe operator

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to load a very large JSON file and bind it to a variable, here is my code that is failing.....

```
deps = File.open("../DepMap.json")
    |> IO.read(:all) 
    |> JSX.decode
```

I'm getting back

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :io.request/2
(stdlib) io.erl:556: :io.request({:error, :enoent}, {:get_line, :unicode, ""})
(elixir) lib/io.ex:82: IO.do_read_all/2
lib/depchecker.ex:6: (module)
(stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
```

What am I missing here? I'm assuming that the result of File.open gets passed as the first arguement to IO.read(:all) but this is the point of failure here and I'm not sure how to rectify this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`File.open` returns either `{:ok, pid}` or `{:error, reason}`. The second one in cases when it fails. Here you're getting `{:error, :enoent}` meaning the file does not exist - you'll probably need to figure out what's wrong with your path there.

You might also want to use the bang version of `File.open` in your pipeline:

```
deps = File.open!("../DepMap.json")
|> IO.read(:all) 
|> JSX.decode
```

This one behaves like `File.open`, but raises an exception instead of returning an error value. On success though it just returns the `pid` representing the file, which is what you need for the `IO.read` call.

Comment: Thank you, i resolved my path and then used the bang which corrected my other error after.